# moved downloads and back and now i have 2 downloads folders

Tags: hard-drive, regedit

I accidentally moved my downloads folder to f drive and when i moved it back my f drive still looks like downloads and has all the downloads files please help i used registry edit to move it.

Answer (score 1):

> please help i used registry edit to move [Downloads]

Best to move it by Downloads Properties and not the Registry (not a user tool).

Best approach (my point of view) would be to back up ALL documents, delete the Download folder(s), restart and recreate it, locating where you want.

There is nothing particularly different about Downloads that most other folders (except that it is a System Folder instead of File Folder), but of course, Microsoft provided Downloads along with other folders (e.g. Pictures) as basic built in folders.

If you are certain about what you are doing, you might try reversing the registry entry.

Here is additional Microsoft information about Downloads.

[Recreate Downloads folder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/deleted-downloads-folder-by-mistake/d3a3c54e-8f8e-468e-9e36-e662534e2c8c)

Comment: Worth pointing out that, while you can redirect the folder, you have to move the files yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that the designated Downloads folder is associated with it's desired location by ensuring that Downloads under This PC is pointing to that folder.

If you've removed the folders from This PC, you can check the path with **PowerShell**:

- `(New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace("shell:Downloads").Self.Path`

Then:

- Open the "fake" `Downloads` folder
- + in the folder *background* and select `Open PowerShell window here`
- IN the **PowerShell** console, execute the following two commands:

  ```
   ri desktop.ini -force
   (gi .).Attributes -= 'ReadOnly'
  ```

That will remove the custom icon and the *LocalizedResourceName*, which can override the actual file system name.